# framework7 cordova-plugin-googlemaps v2 z-index issue

Tags: google-maps, cordova, html-framework-7

I'm trying to use https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps in framework7 project

but I'm facing a problem

as i navigate to the map page The image is loaded but wasn't displayed

I think the issue is z-index

I tried that solution

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues/2028

but doesn't work

## this is the page before map page

[image]

## the red div is the place where image should display

[image]

## after functions run i see that instead of map

[image]

I use this code to navigate to the map page

```
 success: function (response) {
                        var responseObj = JSON.parse(response)
                        console.log(responseObj);
                        this.$root.navigate("/theMapPage/")

                    }
```

Comment: .map {
  width: 90%;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5%;
  position: relative;
}

that is the map red  div style  and at page loading i convert its background to red

Comment: i found that the plugin make the div background transparent  and display the map behind the div ; how i can set z-index of the map ??

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

as I posted in comment that the plugin make the map behind the application

so I hide all pages and show the current page only

```
 map.one(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, function () {
                        $$('.page').hide()
                        $$('.page.page-current').show()
                        map.clear();
                        map.getMyLocation(onSuccess, onError);
                    });
```

at end just show all pages again

```
        pageAfterOut: function () {
            // page has left the view
            $$('.page').show()
        }
```